# How to assign diff date format to other in react native?

Tags: react-native, datetime

I am working on react native app

I have the following code

```
if(resultFltLeg.estArrTime){
    console.log("datecheck " + resultFltLeg.estArrTime);
    console.log("datecheck-1 " + myFltLeg.estArrTime);

    myFltLeg.estArrTime = Date(resultFltLeg.estArrTime);  //want to assign this correctly

    console.log("datecheck-2 " + myFltLeg.estArrTime);
    console.log("datecheck-3 " + Date(resultFltLeg.estArrTime));

  }`enter code here`
```

getting console log as below

```
datecheck 2020-10-12 16:50:00
datecheck-1 Mon Oct 12 2020 16:42:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

datecheck-2 Mon Oct 12 2020 16:46:16 GMT+0530 (IST)
datecheck-3 Mon Oct 12 2020 16:46:16 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Why timing is changing from  16:50:00 to 16:46:16 (current time) after assign?
How can I assign date so that I can get proper date?

Comment: `let dateString = "2020-10-12 16:06:00"; let dateObj = new Date(dateString); console.log(dateObj);`   It works!!

Comment: Please try the above code.

Comment: @AlphaDevs Thanks for help//but still getting same result

Comment: @AlphaDevs Please find updated question

Comment: it works on my side. Could you let me know the exact code you tried to test, please?